# Как копировать файлы CSS в Gulp?

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

Я хочу подключить slick-slider в свою gulp сборку.
Я подключаю его в scss но так как там нужны для работы шрифты, это не срабатывает т.к. gulp сборка на них не реагирует.
Тогда я закидываю файл slick.css в папку css, но он почему то не копирует его в dist.

```js
    const gulp = require('gulp');
    const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
    const watch = require('gulp-watch');

    const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
    const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
    const sourcemap = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
    const pug = require('gulp-pug')
    const del = require('del')

    gulp.task('pug', (callback) => {
    return gulp.src('./src/pug/pages/**/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
     callback()
     })


    gulp.task('scss', (callback) => {
    return gulp.src('./src/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemap.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ['last 4 versions']
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemap.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    callback()
    });

    gulp.task('cleanbuild', () => {
    return del('./build')
    })

    gulp.task('copyimg', (callback) => {
    return gulp.src('./src/img/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img/'))
    callback()
    })


    gulp.task('copyjs', (callback) => {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'))
    callback()
    })

    gulp.task('watch', () => {
    watch(['./build/js/**/*.*', './build/img/**/*.*'], gulp.parallel(browserSync.reload))
    watch(['./src/scss/**/*.scss'], gulp.parallel('scss'))
    watch(['./src/pug/**/*.pug'], gulp.parallel('pug'))
    watch(['./src/img/**/*.*'], gulp.parallel('copyimg'))
    watch(['./src/js/**/*.*'], gulp.parallel('copyjs'))
    });


    gulp.task('server', () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build/"
        }
    });
    });

    gulp.task('default',
    gulp.series(
        gulp.parallel('cleanbuild'),
        gulp.parallel('scss', 'pug', 'copyimg', 'copyjs'),
        gulp.parallel('server', 'watch')
    )
    );

    gulp.task('css', (callback) => {
    return gulp.src('./src/css/*.css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    callback()
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что-то типа `gulp.src('FROM').pipe(gulp.dest('TO'))`  не сработает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function css() {
    return gulp
        .src([
            "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
            "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css",
        ])
        .pipe(concat("_libs.scss"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/scss"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
}
```

Это таск, который соединяет все библиотеки CSS и не только в один файл (libs.scss), по моему примеру вы можете вдохновиться .